# PCI Soundcard support

Tags: ubuntu-studio, soundcard, midi

I'm trying to set a PC to learn Ubuntu-Studio (release 18).
I'm using an old PCI soundcard: Guillemot Fortissimo I.
Expecting to use MIDI I/O to connect to my piano keyboard.
Testing with live CD, seems that my soundcard is recognized but NOT the MIDI part.

Is there any additional driver I should install or configure ?
Which command could I use to check the MIDI ?

Thank you.

Here is lspci command output, showing the Yamaha YMF-744B soundcard.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 1
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 5
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 6
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 90)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JIR (ICH10R) LPC Interface Controller
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 4 port SATA IDE Controller #1
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 2 port SATA IDE Controller #2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G92 [GeForce 8800 GT] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 Gigabit or Fast Ethernet (rev b0)
03:00.0 IDE interface: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE6111/6121 SATA II / PATA Controller (rev b2)
05:01.0 Multimedia audio controller: Yamaha Corporation YMF-744B [DS-1S Audio Controller] (rev 02)
05:03.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): LSI Corporation FW322/323 [TrueFire] 1394a
```

Here is the output of aconnect -i

```
client 0: 'System' [type=noyau]
    0 'Timer           '
    1 'Announce        '
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=noyau]
    0 'Midi Through Port-0'
```

Comment: There is no version of Ubuntu called 18.

Comment: The os version reported by alsa-info is : Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 1):

The MIDI (and FM synth) devices are not enabled by default, probably because earlier versions of the YMF-7xx chip did not have Plug&Play support for those.

To enable these devices, add a line like the following to some file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`, most likely `alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-ymfpci mpu_port=1 fm_port=1
```

Comment: With this in your answer -add a line like the following to some file - it is not a clear answer.

Comment: Hello again, I have upgraded to version 20.04.3 LTS, then added the line "options snd-ymfpci mpu_port=1 fm_port=1" at the end of the file /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf. Then reboot (do not know if it is necessary). Apparently it does not solve the issue. aconnect -i still gives me the same result. Another point is the content of the file /proc/asound/cards is showing only one card (HDA Intel of the Motherboard), I was expecting to see my  YMF744 card here. Probably missing something as I'm really a beginner. Any Idea? Thank you

Comment: @demeli That is a different question. Check that it shows up in `lspci`, then run `rmmod snd-ymfpci; modprobe snd-ymfpci` and check the system log for errors, and ask a new question.